# Can I declare a 'polymorphic' axiom in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'd like to have an axiom which accepts either a `nat` or a `bool` and returns a `nat`. Something like

```
Axiom poly_axiom {A : Set}: A -> nat.
```

But Coq refused to accept such a 'polymorphic' axiom. Is there any way to do that?

Irrelevant note: the purpose of defining such a weird axiom is to use poly_axiom to calculate the number of axioms used in term t, where t is of type A and t is 'wrapped' inside poly_axiom. There is another axiom defining how to reduce t inside axiom poly_axiom. It's also welcome to see a better solution to this problem.

Comment: May I ask why you want to have a function declared as a Coq axiom for doing this?

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim I imagined it could be a recursive function. However, I don't know how to unfold/pattern-match *a serial of function invocations* as they are not defined inductively. For example, inside a function f, there is 'f1 p1 >> f2'. Suppose f1 is declared as an axiom, and there is another axiom specifying its semantics, I want to calculate *how many abstract functions there are in this serial*. Then the axiom poly_axiom can match f1 p1 and return 1 + poly_axiom f2 (result f1 p1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike with `Definition`s (and `Theorem`s, etc.), you cannot write variable names on the left hand side of the colon when declaring `Axiom`s. You have to use a `forall` like so:

```
Axiom poly_axiom : forall {A : Set}, A -> nat.
```